# 9-patch tiled style image

Tags: android, nine-patch

I cant deal with my 9patch tool to create button (shape) with tiled style background

What image I have:

[image: what i have]

What I want to be using 9patch format...

[image: what i want]

Pay attention to the tiles (grid) inside this button. When I make my 9patch, the grid  stretches wrongly and I cant get such result as in the second image

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with 9patches. You can only mark a region ("patch") to stretch, not repeat.